# document.referrer and close()

Tags: javascript, if-statement, referrer

I have the below script on a page, let's say "child.html".

I only want the browser to see the function `opener.opener = opener; opener.close()` if the referring URL is the one listed in the `if` statement of the script (parent.html), otherwise I don't want the browser to see it.

The page that this script is on is a child page (a popup) of a parent page. Users (hopefully) will only access the parent page, which will subsequently open this child page and close the parent page at the same time using the `opener.opener = opener; opener.close()` function.

The function works fine and does what I need it to do (closes the parent after opening the popup). **But**, if the child page URL is accessed directly (in other words without being directed from the parent page), then obviously there is no parent page to close and I get the script error:

'opener' is null or not an object

I understand the error message, hence why I'm trying to hide 'opener' if the referring URL **IS NOT** parent.html so that if someone happens to access the child page directly, opener is hidden and no error message.

What do I need to change in the below script to make this work?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[<!--
        if (document.referrer != '../parent.html') {
        opener.opener = opener;
        opener.close();}
        else {}
        //-->
        //]]>
        </script>
```

Alternatively, I tried writing the following:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[<!--
        if (document.referrer = '../parent.html') {
        return false;
        } else {
        opener.opener = opener;
        opener.close();}
        //-->
        //]]>
        </script>
```

But that returns the script error: 'return' statement outside of function.

Thanks very much in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: first of all, if you want to write down a function, you have to declare it and then invoke like: function myFunc(...) {//your code with return} myFunc(...)

Comment: for your first piece of code try something like if (document.referrer != '../parent.html' && opener) {....}

Comment: My pleasure, I'll put in a answer way for both of pieces :) (Actually I'm at work and I hadn't time for a good answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first script is correct if you put an `AND`condition with the initialization of opener variable like:

```
 if (document.referrer !== '../popup.html' && opener) { ... }
```

For the second one you have to write down a function if you want to use the `return` statement like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[<!--
   function(){
     function myFunct() {
       if (document.referrer === '../parent.html' || !opener) {
         return false;
       } else {
         opener.opener = opener;
         opener.close();
         return true;
       }
    }
    myFunct();
   }();​
   //-->
   //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Much appreciated Dario, thanks for your thorough explanation and examples :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dario for the suggestion :) I rewrote it and the below script works:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[<!--
        if (document.referrer != '../popup.html' && opener) { 
        opener.opener = opener;
        opener.close();}
        //-->
        //]]>
        </script>
```